# JQuery: Split Image and cause splits to disappear on mouseover

Tags: jquery, css, image

I am attempting to make a puzzle website for a university project and one of the puzzles I've thought of has been driving me a bit crazy. I want to have the page take a png image, split it into a bunch of 32px by 34px squares, and have those those squares disappear when the cursor is over them.

Here is a rough diagram of what I want: 
[Rough Diagram](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4222914/s%27cool/Web/advwebproj2/Puzzle2Diagram.jpg)
(Ignore the slider things)

The closest I've found is a certain part of [this tutorial](http://marakana.com/s/post/1175/jquery_puzzle_image_tutorial_plugin_ui) where the image gets split into different puzzle pieces but I can't seem to take the code he uses and rework it to do what I need to do.

I know it's probably stupidly complicated and very situational, but I don't think it should be too hard... hopefully.

Edit: I've not tried much as I am not really a jQuery user or coder in any way. What I've used so far I barely understand and probably won't be of much use but I can post it.

I made a .js file called image_split.js and it contains this:

```
(function($)
{
    $.fn.jSplit=function(options)
{
                var piece=$('<span></span>').addId("curtain" +     this.id.substring(4)).css(
        {
            'width': 32+'px',
            'height': 34+'px',
            'display': 'inline-block',
            'float': 'left',
            'background-image': 'url("images/curtain.png")',
            'background-position': (-32)+'px '+(-34)+'px',
        })
};
})(jQuery);
```

and then called it in the HTML.

```
<script>            
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#actor').jSplit();
        });
</script>
```

That was meant to split the image. As for making it disappear, I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $("div[id^=curtain]").hover(
            function(){
                $("#curtain" + this.id.substring(4)).css({"visibility":"visible"});
            },
            function(){
                $("#curtain" + this.id.substring(4)).css({"visibility":"hidden"});
            }
        );
      });
</script>
```

I know it's not working and I'm sure all this code is terrible, but if it helps you guys than all the better, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you some base, however without the html that gets generated, its kind of difficult to give a proper answer, I will do my best however. I've included a JSFiddle with an example. I'm not entirely sure how you are adding the `<span>` tags, however I'm lazy so i handled it in jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/vmex151/xvvvy/

Is that something like what you are looking for?